# Stream movie from PC/raspberry to xbox via nodejs

Tags: node.js, xbox-one

I want to know if it's possible to stream a video from a pc to an xbox and use the app moview & tv ?
For example i want to reproduce this feature : 
[image]

Anybody know the protocol or the api used for this ?

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my question. DLNA can provide this feature. So I take a nodejs lib for dlna client and play my video.